# Errors in F# Interactive when trying to reference to dlls related to WPF

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0

I'm trying to run some WPF related code in FSI.I'm able to run the same code as a part of WPF project, so that means that everything is fine with that code.
I have three references:

```
#r @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\7.0.5\PresentationFramework.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\7.0.5\PresentationCore.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\7.0.5\WindowsBase.dll"
```

For some reason second reference is being underlined by mine IDE(Rider) with following error:
`A reference to the type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' in assembly 'WindowsBase' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly`

Also my IDE shows some strange errors in errors view and if try to navigate to them it navigates to the top of the file and that errors are:

```
The module/namespace 'System.Windows' from compilation unit 'WindowsBase' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'Freezable'
The module/namespace 'System.Windows' from compilation unit 'WindowsBase' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'DependencyObject'
```

If I just run FSI and pass that three `#r` statements, no error will be shown but then if I try to do this: `open System.Windows`, I'll get:
`stdin(3,1): error FS1109: A reference to the type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' in assembly 'WindowsBase' was found, but the type could not be found in that assembly`

So the in general I need this bit of code to be working:

```
#r @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\7.0.5\PresentationFramework.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\7.0.5\PresentationCore.dll"
#r @"C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\7.0.5\WindowsBase.dll"

open System.Windows
```

I've tried to rearrange that `#r` statements, tried to use dlls from `refs` folder (e.g. `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref\7.0.5\ref\net7.0\WindowsBase.dll`). Any thoughts how can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373859/running-forms-forms-f-script-in-net-5

Comment: You should still be able to do it with the classic framework (and classic FSI, obviously), if that's any help.

Comment: @JimFoye, sorry, but I’m running WPF application, on net core, so where I’m working with “classic” framework? and why net core fsi isn’t working?

Comment: @BentTranberg, the link that you sent is related to WinForms, again sorry but I thought that WPF is some kind of modern stuff, so expect it to work

Comment: You're not working with the classic framework, I know. Something is different with .NET Core, in the .NET Core WPF libraries, and/or the .NET Core version of FSI. So if you want to do F# scripting with WPF, you may have to fall back to the classic framework. I've done this, and you can see examples in Expert F# (written by Don Syme), so that should still work. BTW, Microsoft doesn't consider WPF to be "modern", even though many of us think it was the best desktop GUI framework that they ever created. They like to change APIs constantly, regardless of what investment their customers have made.

Comment: @MichaelSamoilenko, then you didn't read everything in that link. Anyway, the conclusion there seems to be that you can't do it.

Comment: @JimFoye, I have opened "Expert F#" book and I can't see any examples, can you please point me/help me, what exact things do you mean?
we can have a chat in some messager (e.g Discord)/email 
many thanks! waiting for your reply

Comment: I wonder whether LINQPad has somehow implemented a solution for using WPF that could also be exploited in scripts, though I certainly will not bet on that. Another route you might consider is to actually use LINQPad for your scripting, and have access to WPF that way. But just using any other solution might be better in the long run. E.g. Elmish.WPF makes WPF simple with F#.

Comment: @BentTranberg, sorry, but I think I don't understand how can I use for example Elmish. You mean I need totally rewrite my app with using that library?
I think the suitable solution is to use classic framework, but I don't know how

Comment: Expert F#, 3.0, page 465. He opens a WPF window from a script. I should have specified which edition, though I would think the same example is in the later edition (maybe it isn't).

Comment: First, classic framework means .NET Framework, to be exact. That's yesterday's technology, which you definitely shouldn't use for new development, and I suggest not for learning either. Second, don't waste time making large professional WPF applications using code-behind, and especially not code-behind in F#. You'll drown in issues. You can go with MVVM in C# and still use F# for business logic, but we F#'ers tend to use various Elmish implementations to make life really easy. It will boost your performance from the very start.

Comment: @BentTranberg, thank you. Make sense. I think for me the acceptable solution is to run my script code in net framework based fsi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example from the book, Expert F# 3.0. I just tried this and it works (with classic FSI, obviously).

```
#r "WindowsBase"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "PresentationFramework"
#r "System.Xaml"
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
let w = new Window()
let b = new Button(Content = "Hello from WPF!")
b.Click.Add(fun _ -> w.Close())
w.Content <- b
w.Show()
```

In the next edition, Expert F# 4.0, this example has been replaced with an example using Eto Forms, because, you know, the whole world gave up on WPF and moved on to Eto Forms.

Comment: many thanks, I'm accepting that answer. I was able to run my code when I started classic (net framework) FSI